# Invalid query: Incorrect key file for table

Tags: mysql

There is couple of these already. My question though is how can something like this happen? is it cause by a bug in my code or is it an apache related problem?

```
Invalid query: Incorrect key file for table '/tmpfs/#sql_8e2_1.MYI'; try to repair it
```

Comment: I voted to close this question, A: I have no idea what you're talking about. B: what exactly happens? C: What code? D: what's the link with apache?

Comment: Which version of mysql are you running? Did the server lose power or crash?

Comment: It is running 5.0 version. I have no access to the server since I am using hosting solution. This is actually why I am asking about the possiblity that this could be cause by my own code. Johan - If you have no idea, it's not necessary problem of a question ;)

Comment: is a valid problem, where the index file is corrupted, contact your hosting provider to fix

Comment: the tmp folder has a limit usually 2GB, try df -h to see it. For big queries this is usually the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of mysql are you running? Are there open bugs which could cause this problem with the version you're running? Did the server lose power or crash?

Consider using the repair table syntax:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html

Please note all the **warnings** about making backups before running this.

Comment: It is running 5.0 version. I have no access to the server since I am using hosting solution. This is actually why I am asking if there is a  possiblity that this could be caused by my own code. I've tried using Repair before (The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair...) but this is not a problem. I've just restored db. I only have to make sure that this isn't cause by a bug in my code since it is a client work and I'd like to avoid fixing db every day.

Comment: Version 5.0 is from 2005, there are lots of known bugs (google search: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,362974,363984#msg-363984) Consider moving hosts if they won't upgrade

Comment: Yep that is the last supported version. Gonna try another hosting. So can I be sure that this isn't cause by a bug in my own code?

Comment: Set it up on your development system (perhaps your own PC?) and test it. I can't be sure without seeing your code, but the version of MySQL isn't doing you or your client any favors.

Comment: Thanks, I am testing in on localhost on newer version of mysql as well, so far no problem.

Comment: Well if your host won't upgrade ( I know a few who don't do this sort of thing for one reason or another ) I'd say take your business elsewhere, there's no good reason to have your client get narky with you for something you can't change :)